# R, compare certain values of specific period (such as April - next Mar) to the previous year

Tags: r, compare

I'd like to produce line graph to compare, let's say, the air quality from 2019-04 to 2020-03, with 2018-04 to 2019-03.

I did some search but didn't find any solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: One way would be to create a variable with two groups indicating the period. Then use that as a facetting variable in a ggplot, allowing the date axis to roam free (`scales="free"`). But without some data, I can only imagine doing that in my head and I don't know if that would work. Could you provide a sample dataset?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done a couple of ways. I've used the *mydata* data set from the **openair** package which records hourly air quality measurements in London from Jan 1998 - Jun 2005.

The first step is to create a "Period" variable defining the two periods. Here I've compared April, 2003 - March, 2004 with April, 2004 - March, 2005. These are two 12-month periods that cross over the two calendar years. The next step is to change the date of the first period by adding 365 days. This is a bit of a "fudge" because leap years *may* be a problem. But I'll just gloss over that for the sake of simplicity. If you really want to align the days correctly, then a more rigorous method may be required (if any - I'm wondering if this fudge may be ok).

```
data <- mydata %>%
  mutate(Date=as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Ozone=mean(o3)) %>%  # Aggregate to get average daily ozone (optional)
  # Filter the data to be plotted
  filter(Date>=as.Date("2003-04-01") & Date<=as.Date("2005-03-31")) %>%
  # Create the period variable
  mutate(Period=ifelse(Date<as.Date("2004-04-01"), "1", "2"),
  # Modify the date for the second period to align with that of the first period (fudge)
         Date=as.Date(ifelse(Period=="1", Date+365, Date), origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Option 1: Show both series on the same plot.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(y=Ozone, x=Date, col=Period)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  scale_color_discrete(name="", 
                       labels=c("Apr, 2003 - Mar, 2004    ",  # add a gap here :)
                                "Apr, 2004 - Mar, 2005")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="months", date_minor_breaks="months", date_labels="%b")

p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

---

[image]

---

Option 2: Facetting, with optional secondary axes on top (substract 365 to get original dates).

```
p + facet_wrap(~Period, nrow=2) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", strip.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks="months", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . - 365))
```

[image]

The first period (in red) is in the top panel.

---

**First version**:
Perhaps something like this?

```
data(airquality)

airquality$Period <- ifelse(airquality$Month<7, 1, 2)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

airquality %>%
  mutate(Date = ISOdate(1973, Month, Day)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=Ozone:Temp, names_to="Measurement") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value, x=Date, color=Measurement)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  facet_grid(~Period, labeller=label_both, scales="free_x") # <- try without scales="free_x"
```

---

[image]

---

**Edit**: OP would prefer to see both groups in one graph. This is possible, if it makes sense, such as when comparing daily or monthly averages for different calendar years as shown in the following example. One way to do this is to create a year variable based on the date, then change the "year" component of all dates to be equal.

```
library(openair)   # For the data, "mydata"
library(lubridate) # Simplifies many date conversions (month, day)

mydata %>%  # hourly air pollutant concentrations in London 1998-2005 (see help page)
  mutate(Date=as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%  # Remove time unit
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Ozone=mean(o3)) %>%  # Calculate averages per day
  filter(Date>=as.Date("2003-01-01") & Date<as.Date("2004-12-31")) %>%  # Choose two years
  mutate(Year=format(Date, "%Y"), 
         Date=as.Date(paste(2003, month(Date), day(Date), sep="-"))) %>%  # The trick
  ggplot(aes(y=Ozone, x=Date, col=Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 months", date_labels="%b")
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but what I am thinking is comparison in one plot. For example, only look at Ozone in Dec, Jan and Feb, there will be only one plot, X axis is from Dec to Feb, two lines represent Ozone numbers from the latest winter and the previous winter. Any idea?

Comment: That's certainly doable, but unless you're comparing similar units of time, for example daily or monthly averages for two consecutive years, then the axis will look confusing. In the example I posted, the graph would look very strange. I'll edit my post and show an example using another dataset.

Comment: Sorry that I did stress my problem clearly. The key of my problem is that the period I want to compare cross two year, it's a comparison between period from 2019-12 to 2020-02, and period from 2018-12 to 2019-02.  So, the x axis is not in a m=normal order, it will be Dec - Jan - Feb. It's not a regular year-over-year comparison.

Comment: What I'm thinking is: the scale limits on x axis are Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb. The first line shows values from Nov, 2018 to Feb, 2019, the second line shows values from Nov, 2019 to Feb, 2020. So the most difficult part is that each line represents values from two different years. Think about data during the Covid-19 outbreak, you want to show the economy drop, first you want to see the trend from the previous two month to the lastest two month, you also want to compare this period with the same period in the previous years.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I just did. Subtract 365 days to align the two series on the same x-axis. It won't matter is some months are missing or not.